# How to call python function from scala?

Tags: python, pandas, scala

Lets say I have an entity **X** with some fields.

I have a `python function` that expects `panda dataframes` of entity X. It does some calculations, updates one of the field of X with machine learning algorithm [ [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) ] and finally returns the updated dataframes of X.

On the other side, I have a `scala code` that has `List of entity X`. Now, I also have to calculate the value of that field of X in the same way as the python counterpart does.

Now it would be extremely difficult to simulate the similar machine learning stuff again in scala.
The easiest way I see would be to re-use/call that python function somehow and get updated List of X.

Is there some way to achieve this ?
Any insights or suggestions on how to solve this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it is not possible. Because your `X` _entities_ in **Scala** are not the same ones in **Python** _(even if they have the same attributes, they are encoded differently)_ - Also, even if they would be the same, you cannot access the memory of one process from another. However, you may share a serialized representation _(**Binary** or **JSON**)_ of the objects between the two processes. You may write then to a file and then launch the python script which will read it, or use sockets, or shared memory. Or maybe [**GraalVM**](https://www.graalvm.org/) may do the trick.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 or earlier (unlikely), you may be able to use Jython. You'll have to perform your own X <-> Dataframe translation though.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will help you call the python script from scala itself.

```
import sys.process._
def callPython(){
     val result = "python /fullpath/mypythonprogram.py" ! 
        ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)
println(result)
println("stdout: " + stdout)
println("stderr: " + stderr)
}
```

Comment: This is not what exactly what I was looking for... Anyways, I tried to execute this but didn't work. Nothing got printed on the console.

Answer (score -1):

try this code 
val result = "python /fullpath/mypythonprogram.py" !! ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)

Because "!" will just return 0 or 1 (0 stands for function is executed without error and 1 stands for function through error)

Hope it works for you.
thanks.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Provide an extended explanation on how your answer works.